# K&R exercise 2.6 bit minipulation

Tags: c

"Write a function setbits(x, p, n, y) that returns x with the n bits that begin at position p set to the rightmost n bits of y, leaving the other bits unchanged."

I'm having trouble figuring out what I did wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
unsigned setbits(unsigned int x, int p, int n, unsigned y);

int main()
{
    unsigned x = 213;
    unsigned y = 121;
    int p = 4;
    int n = 4;

    x = setbits(x, p, n, y);
    printf("%u\n", x);

    getch();
    return 0;
}
unsigned setbits(unsigned x, int p, int n, unsigned y)
{
    return ((~(~0 << n) & y) << (p + 1 - n) | (~(~(~0 << n)) << (p + 1 - n) & x));
}
```

On paper I'm getting 211 as a result, but my code is producing 210. The K&R answer book algorithm is also returning 210. I can't figure out what I did wrong here.

Edit: Here is the code from the answer book:

```
unsigned setbits(unsigned x, int p, int n, unsigned y)
{
    return x & ~(~(~0 << n) << (p + 1 - n)) | (y & ~(~0 << n)) << (p + 1 - n);
}
```

Re-edit. I figured it out while breaking up the code into separate lines. The problem was a misplaced parenthesis next to the last x:

```
//original
{
    return ((~(~0 << n) & y) << (p + 1 - n) | (~(~(~0 << n)) << (p + 1 - n) & x));
}

//fixed
{
    return ((~(~0 << n) & y) << (p + 1 - n)) | (~(~(~0 << n) << (p + 1 - n)) & x);
}
```

Here is the code broken up. Does this still look bad? Should I be using variables like this:

```
int setbits(unsigned x, int p, int n, unsigned y)
{
    unsigned z, k;

    z = y & ~(~0 << n);
    z = z << (p + 1 - n);
    k = ~((~(~0 << n)) << (p + 1 - n));
    k = k & x;

    return z | k;
}
```

Comment: Show your steps. I can't tell where you went wrong this way.

Comment: ... neither can I. In other words, that code isn't very easy to read or understand. Perhaps if you factor it up a bit, it becomes clearer?

Comment: I'm sure I'm being slow here, but what's `u`? (And can you show your paper working too?)

Comment: An important lesson can be learned here: it's not clever to write a complicated expression in one line - it makes it hard to read/understand and even harder to debug. Re-factor your setbits function into several lines, each containing a simpler expression - the generated code will be no less efficient, and you'll be able to step through the code in your debugger and inspect the intermediate results.

Comment: I guess I wouldn't need 100 parenthesis if I separated it all eh? I'll try that out. K&R example and answer book have it all in one line too tho.

Comment: @Spellbinder2050: terseness was somewhat useful in Ye Olden Dayes of teletypes and 24x80 CRT displays (and compilers were much less sophisticated), but it's counter-productive now that screen resolutions are so much higher (and compilers are so much smarter) - readability and ease of debugging are way more important considerations when writing code now.

Comment: Paul, thanks. I'm in the middle of rewriting this. It might take a while. =[

Comment: K I fixed it. Check it out.

Comment: @Spellbinder2050: Much better, but I would also factor out `~(~0 << n)` into a separate `const`, e.g. `const unsigned mask = ~(~0 << n);`.

Comment: ok. Yeah I wasn't sure how people do this. A full bit minipulation algorithm example would be fine if you have a link. Although the subject in K&R is short and I probably won't need this again.

Answer (score 0):

The wording is a bit difficult to follow but I think this is what it is asking for:

```
unsigned setbits(unsigned int x, int p, int n, unsigned y){
  return x | ((y&((1<<n)-1))<<(p-n));
}
```

```
unsigned setbits(unsigned int x, int p, int n, unsigned y){
  return (x & ~(((1<<n)-1)<<(p-n))) | ((y&((1<<n)-1))<<(p-n));
}
```

breakdown:

- left half of |

  - `((1<<n)-1)` will shift 1 n bits to the left, subtracting 1 makes all bits to the right 1.
  - `<<(p-n)` shift them left by p-n
  - `~` invert them leaving those bits as 0s and everything else 1s
  - `x &` and it to `x` to turn those bits to 0s.
- Right half of |

  - `((1<<n)-1)` same as above
  - `y &` will mask only those bits
  - `<<(p-n)` will shift those bits p-n to the left
  - `left | right` will OR the values together so that:

    - the `n` bits that begin at position `p` are set to the rightmost `n` bits of `y`, leaving the other bits of `x` unchanged

Comment: This isn't quite right. If bits `p..p+n` are ones in `x`, they will not change.

Comment: @egur ... the "leaving the other bits unchanged" threw me off

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm and my solution:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

/* ALGORITHM

1. Sets to 0 all bits in 'x' that will be replaced by rightmost 'n' bits of 'y'. It'll produce a result 'a'.
2. Sets to 0 all bits in 'y' that won't be used as replacement for 'n' bits in 'x', beginning at position 'p'. It'll produce a result 'b'.
3. Apply left-shift operator 'p - n + 1' times in 'b'. This will produce a result 'c', that will let all replacement bits of 'b' in the same position at replaced bits in 'x'.
4. Apply OR binary operator between 'a' and 'c'. The result is what we're gonna output.

*/

unsigned int setbits(unsigned int x, int p, int n, unsigned int y);
int main(void) {
    printf("setbits(181, 4, 2, 155) == %d\n", setbits(181, 4, 2, 155));
    return 0;
}

unsigned int setbits(unsigned int x, unsigned int p, unsigned int n, unsigned int y) {
    unsigned int k = p - n + 1;
    unsigned int j = ~(~0 << n);
    
    return (~(j << k) & x) | ((y & j) << k);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
unsigned setbits(unsigned x, int p, int n, int y) {
   return x | (~(~0 << n) << p);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

#### Solution from the book

```
unsigned setbits(unsigned x, int p, int n, unsigned y)
{
    return x & ~(~(~0 << n) << (p + 1 - n)) | (y & ~(~0 << n)) << (p + 1 - n);
}
```

### When `p=4`

#### The `x` component

`l1 = ~0 => 1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111`
`l2 = l1 << n => 1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_0000`
`l3 = ~(l2) => 0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_1111`
`l4 = (p + 1 - n) => 1`
`l5 = (l3) << (l4) => 0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0001_1110`
`l6 = ~l5 => 1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1110_0001`
`l7 = x & l6 => xxxx_xxxx_xxxx_xxxx_xxxx_xxxx_xxx0_000x`

#### The `y` component

`s1 = ~0 => 1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111`
`s2 = s1 << n => 1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_0000`
`s3 = ~s2 => 0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_1111`
`s4 = (p + 1 - n) => 1`
`s5 = s3 << s4 => 0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0001_1110`
`s6 = y & s5 => 0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_000y_yyy0`

`o = l7 | s6`

#### output

`xxxx_xxxx_xxxx_xxxx_xxxx_xxxx_xxxy_yyyx`
`^all these uncounted bits!!!^         .`

> Write a function setbits(x, p, n, y) that returns x with the n bits that **begin at position p set to the *rightmost*** n bits of y, leaving the other bits unchanged.

Did we start counting from the right with zero and then once reaching position `p` start counting back to the right `n` bits?

`unsigned` is of the type `int` and that can be verified with

`$ gcc -o ansi-c_2-6 *.c -std=c89`
`$ ansi-c_2-6`

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  printf("%s", (sizeof(unsigned) == sizeof(int)) ? "TRUE" : "FALSE");
  return 0;
}
```

## Conclusion

Solution book is wrong.

## Solution

Notes

- `bits = CHAR_BIT * sizeof(`**datatype**`))`
- Right shifts carry the most significant bit. `INT_MIN >> 31 == ~0`
- `if p + n > 32`, you could cast up but that quickly gets out of hand

### `x` stuff

#### left side

`left_mask = INT_MIN >> (p - 1)`

#### right side

`right_mask = INT_MAX >> (p - 1 + n)`

`x = x & (left_mask | right_mask)`

### `y` stuff

#### middle side

`mid_mask = ~(left_mask | right_mask)`

`y = (y << (bits - p - n)) & mid_mask`

### `return` stuff

`x | y`

## TL;DR

### Book is wrong

do this instead

```
unsigned setbits(unsigned x, unsigned char p, unsigned char n, unsigned y)
{
  char bits = CHAR_BIT * sizeof(unsigned);
  unsigned left_mask, right_mask, mid_mask;
  left_mask = p > 0 ? INT_MIN >> (p-1) : 0;
  right_mask = INT_MAX >> (p - 1 + n);
  mid_mask = (left_mask | right_mask) & x;
  x = (left_mask | right_mask) & x;
  y = y << (bits - p - n) & mid_mask;
  return x | y;
}
```

Restrictions:

- `n > 0`
- `p + n < sizeof(unsigned) * CHAR_BIT`